# Cannot install module pp on windows 7 64 bit with Strawberry-Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, pp-perl-par-packager

I would like to create exe files from my perl scripts so therefore I tried to install the modul pp. But the installation failed with this output.

```
cpan> install pp
Database was generated on Tue, 31 Jul 2012 14:02:56 GMT
Running install for module 'pp'
Running make for R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\R\RS\RSCHUPP\PAR-Packer-1.013
.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE


  CPAN.pm: Going to build R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Prototype mismatch: sub main::prompt: none vs ($;$) at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Ex
tUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 219
Writing Makefile for par.exe
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing Makefile for PAR::Packer
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/App/Packer/PAR.pm blib\lib\App\Packer\PAR.pm
cp lib/PAR/Packer.pm blib\lib\PAR\Packer.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Obfuscate.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Obfuscate.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/PodStrip.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PodStrip.pm
cp lib/PAR/StrippedPARL/Base.pm blib\lib\PAR\StrippedPARL\Base.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/PatchContent.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PatchContent.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bytecode.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bytecode.pm
cp lib/pp.pm blib\lib\pp.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bleach.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bleach.pm
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe file2c.pl -s ..\script\par.pl my_par_pl.c load_m
y_par_pl
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe sha1.c.PL
gcc -c -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DHAVE_DES_FCRYPT  -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CON
TEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -DPERL_MSVCRT_READFIX  -I"C:\straw
berry\perl\lib\CORE"  -DPARL_EXE=\"parl.exe\" -s -O2 main.c
windres -F pei-i386 -i winres\pp.rc -o winres\pp.res
windres: can't open file `pp.manifest': No such file or directory
dmake:  Error code 129, while making 'ppresource.coff'
dmake.EXE:  Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'
  RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz              : make NO
```

Does anyone know what the reason is? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the `pp` makefile.

1.Download the PM manually ([Here](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.013/)).

2.Unzip the file and find the `myldr/winres` folder.

3.There will be files like `pp.ico, pp.manifest, pp.rc` etc. Copy these files to `myldr/` directory.

4.Run the install manually.

```
  perl Makefile.pl
  dmake 
  dmake test 
  dmake install
```

Note- There might be dependancies so you may have to install those manually or using `CPAN`.

Comment: I tried it like you describe but the dmake command was not succesfull, I could see that there is a error message 'code' Can't locate PAR/Filter/PodStrip.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:\Downloads\PAR-Pac 'code'
ker-1.013\PAR-Packer-1.013\myldr\blib\arch D:\Downloads\PAR-Packer-1.013\PAR-Pac
ker-1.013\myldr\blib\lib C:/strawberry/perl/lib C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib

Comment: Then I tried to install PAR::Filter::PodStrip but received the error Running install for module 'PAR::Filter::PodStrip'
Running make for R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\strawberry\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-
1.013-Q4Q7Ot
Could not make: Unknown error
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

Comment: There is a known bug in Strawberry Perl which is responsbile for the failures. Please make the code changes mentioned in the link and then it should work. [Forum Link](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.par/2012/03/msg5310.html) and the [Bug Details](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=75636)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it was because I had ActiveState Perl installed. I had to uninstall ActiveState and edit my environmental variables to remove any reference to ActiveState Perl.